# How to get json object key name from collection and iterate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Below is my json structure. On success of collection.fetch() i'm looping through the structure.

Currently i use

```
this.collection.each(function(model) { .. }
```

How do i obtain key name like plants, animals and instead loop using the names.

JSON

```
var jsonObj = {         // 0 - recommended , 1 - New
   "plants" : [

       {
        "title" : "title1",
            "desc": "description.." 
       },
           {
        "title" : "titl2",
            "desc": "description."  
       }    
    ],
    "animals" : [

       {
        "title" : "title1",
            "desc": "description.." 
       },
           {
        "title" : "titl2",
            "desc": "description."  
       }    
    ]
};
```

Snapshot of collection

[image]

Comment: I would try `this.collection['animals']` etc

Comment: no i would not be knowing the names...i need to get from object.

Comment: `Object.keys(jsonObj)`

Comment: I think you have a collection with one model in it.  And that model has two attributes which are arrays of json (30 items in each).  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: yes correct .. Object.keys work

Answer (score 3):

This would work, but you'd use a normal for loop, not "each":

```
for(i in jsonObj){
     alert(i);
}
```

here is a fjsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5nwP/

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Be careful when using for(i in jsonObj) {...}  It will iterate all the property names not only of your object, but of all parent objects as well.

In the example above, if someone, somewhere else in the javascript that's loaded added Object.prototype.blah = 42; then "blah" would also be alerted.

It is recommended that you include an if statement within your for statement such as: if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) in order to only look at the properties of jsonObj and not parent objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the underscore `keys` to get a list of names:

```
var thenames =_.keys(yourobject);
```

In this case thenames will contain a list of the keys you are looking for.  Here is the documentation for it:

http://underscorejs.org/#keys

keys_.keys(object) 
Retrieve all the names of the object's properties.

_.keys({one : 1, two : 2, three : 3});
=> ["one", "two", "three"]

Comment: i tried this.collection.fetch({
success : function(data) {
data.each(function(item) {
     console.log(_.keys(item.attributes));     });
}
}); I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'keys' of undefined

Comment: It would be _.keys(jsonObj) in your example.